# {JAVA} Rectangle collision detection

Tags: java

**Hi guys,i have 2 questions.

1. why "Hit" word do not appear.
2. what type of code i need to add to make these 2 rects collide and bounce each other based on my code.Just give me a hint . i'll do it myself.
   Below is the code for question 1.
   Thank you.**

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
           
public class f5 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
               
static JFrame frame;
static Timer t;
static int x, velx, x2, velx2;
           
f5() {
               
t = new Timer(5, this);
x = 100;
x2 = 400;
velx = 2;
velx2 = 2;
               
               
       frame = new JFrame();
               
       frame.setSize(500, 400);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.add(this);
            
}
            
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
               
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
               
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, 10, 50, 30);
          
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x2, 10, 50, 30);
           
     if(r1.intersects(r2)){
            g.drawString("HIT!!!!!", 250, 200);
         }

                t.start();
            }    
           
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            if(x < 0 || x > 450) {
                    velx = -velx;
                }
            if(x2 < 0 || x2 > 450) {
                    velx2 = -velx2;
                }
             
             x -= velx;
             x2 += velx2;
           
                 
                  repaint();
            }
           
public static void main(String args[]){
      new f5();
            }
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you not read the *javadoc* for the [no-arg constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle--) of class `Rectangle`?

> Constructs a new Rectangle whose upper-left corner is at (0, 0) in the coordinate space, and whose width and height are both zero.

This means that `r1` and `r2` have zero size and hence they cannot intersect. You need to give `r1` and `r2` dimensions when you create them. Note that method `fillRect()`, in class `java.awt.Graphics`, simply paints a region of the screen. It has nothing to do with `r1` and `r2`. So you should change these two lines in method `paintComponent()`

```java
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
```

to this:

```java
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x, 10, 50, 30);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(x2, 10, 50, 30);
```

Then they will intersect.

---

Regarding your second question. You need to check, in method `actionPerformed()`, whether the rectangles `r1` and `r2` intersect and if they do, you need to reverse the direction of movement – exactly as you do when one of the rectangles reaches the edge of the `JPanel`. In order to do that, you could make `r1` and `r2` members of class `f5`.

The below code shows how to achieve both your requests, i.e. determine when the rectangles intersect and have them "bounce" of each other when they do intersect.

You only require one instance of the `Timer`, so you should not create a new one each time in method `paintComponent()`. You can create it once, in the constructor of class `f5`.

Note that the members of class `f5` should be instance members and not static members. Also note that according to [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), the name of the class should be `F5`.

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
           
public class F5 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Timer t;
    private int x, velx, x2, velx2;
    private Rectangle r1;
    private Rectangle r2;

    F5() {
        t = new Timer(5, this);
        x = 100;
        x2 = 400;
        r1 = new Rectangle(x, 10, 50, 30);
        r2 = new Rectangle(x2, 10, 50, 30);
        velx = 2;
        velx2 = 2;
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        r1 = new Rectangle(x, 10, 50, 30);
        r2 = new Rectangle(x2, 10, 50, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, 10, 50, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x2, 10, 50, 30);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x < 0 || x > 450 || r1.intersects(r2)) {
            velx = -velx;
        }
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > 450 || r1.intersects(r2)) {
            velx2 = -velx2;
        }

        x -= velx;
        x2 += velx2;

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new F5();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really help me a lot. This is the answers i need.

Answer (score 0):

1. The coordinates of rectangles are not defined right now, so they won't intersect (the comparison always return `false`). You are just creating `r1` and `r2` without defining anything. You should initialize them using constructor `new Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`.
2. One way is you can create a class field to store the coordinate of the rectangle, repeatedly check their coordinate to see whether they collide.