# (JAVA) elastic collision effect between moving objects

Tags: java

In the code below, I managed to make these two rectangles bounce at the `JPanel` border, but I cannot make them bounce when they collide (elastic collision). I think there is a problem within `actionPerformed` method (correct me if I am wrong). What should I fix in my code?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
    
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    
public class box {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        objectFrame frame = new objectFrame();
    }   
}
    
class objectFrame extends JFrame {
    objectFrame() {
        objectPanel panel = new objectPanel();
        this.setSize(500, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(panel);
    }
}
    
class objectPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Timer t;
    private int x, velx, x2, velx2;
    private Rectangle r1, r2;
        
    objectPanel() {
        t = new Timer(5, this);
        x = 100;
        x2 = 400;
        velx = 2;
        velx2 = 2; 
        r1 = new Rectangle(x, 10, 50, 30);
        r2 = new Rectangle(x2, 10, 50, 30);
    
        t.start();
    }   
        
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(x, 10, 50, 30);
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(x2, 10, 50, 30);
    
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, 10, 50, 30);
              
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x2, 10, 50, 30);
    }
        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x < 0 || x > 450 || r1.intersects(r2)) {
            velx = -velx;
        }
        if (x2 < 0 || x2 > 450 || r1.intersects(r2)) {
            velx2 = -velx2;
        }
        x += velx;
        x2 -= velx2;
        
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible make these 2 rect collide and bounds at each other without using physic formula? I change the code a bit from the link below(answer provided by abra).                
 {  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840142/java-rectangle-collision-detection/63857599?noredirect=1#comment112928613_63857599    }

Comment: I just need some explanation , why these 2 rects only bound at the border but not bound when thet meet , as i only change a bit from the answer provided by abra in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not simulating the bouncing behavior that considers the mass and direction of colliding objects.

You will need to implement the physics behind an elastic collision to get the effect:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

There is plenty of examples out there. Here's one that I implemented a while back.
https://github.com/gtiwari333/java-collision-detection-source-code.
The collision logic was taken from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20516/ball-collisions-sticking-together.

Comment: I'm too lazy to wade through the code but I want to know how do you determine the mass and velocity of a two dimensional shape on a computer screen?

Comment: Look at the ball class. It expects an initial velocity. The mass is just the radius. :)   https://github.com/gtiwari333/java-collision-detection-source-code/blob/master/src/collision/Ball.java https://github.com/gtiwari333/java-collision-detection-source-code/blob/master/src/collision/PhysicsUtils.java

Comment: When it collides with another object, we update the velocity using the formula.

Comment: is it possible  make these 2 rect collide and bounds at each other without using physic formula? I change  the code a bit from the link below(answer provided by abra).                              {      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840142/java-rectangle-collision-detection/63857599?noredirect=1#comment112928613_63857599   }    .

Comment: I just need some explanation , why these 2 rects only bound at the border but not  bound when thet meet , as i only change a bit from the answer provided by abra in the link.

Comment: The formula simulates the real behavior of objects.